# Project window -> no directory tree lines

Tags: macos, netbeans, macros, netbeans-7.3

I'm working on Mac and every time my project grows I find myself wasting time on finding correct folder in complex directory tree.

I'm used to this https://netbeans.org/images_www/v6/9/screenshots/ruby.png

Now I got this http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/9/96/ScalaEditor_080729_Scala.png

Is it because of MacOS? because I cant find any solution to this either.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non-standard theme? The default Aqua-theme (on MacOs) should look like this 
http://www.jug-bb.de/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/netbeans67beta_osx.jpg